# Variables from variable group are not recognized in azure devops yaml pipeline

Tags: bash, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a variable group e.g. 'vargroup' with 3 variables (env ,envid, envpwd) in azure devops. i have declared the variable group in my yaml definiton too. If i use inline bash script these variables are being recognized and works fine.
However when I use the same script but located in the repository, the script does not recognize the variables in variable group.

```
variables:
- group: vargroup

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    filePath: 'script.sh'
```

my script calls these variables as $(env) , $(envid) , $(envpwd) .

what's the correct way to use the variables from variable group in a script path method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple tries , finally I have found the solution.

trick: using capital letters for passing the variables in the script.

my variables from variable group are env , envid & envpwd.
I have passed them as $ENV , $ENVID , $ENVPWD in my shell script and it worked.

Note: further to make a secret variable like $ENVPWD to work in azure yaml pipeline you will need to pass it as environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can change your script to take arguments and then pass your variables into your script:

```
script.sh $(env) $(envid) $(envpwd)
```